# Redirect site to https, non www including sub domains and contents

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

As the questions suggests, I'd like to redirect my site to non www, https://, and also include all sub domains and their contents. I've tried but i get the 'too many redirects' issue.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me.

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://yourdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```